# Converting a correlated sub-query to JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a correlated subquery which is creating performance issues. Being a correlated subquery it doesn't accept index hints either. So I am trying to convert it into a JOIN instead. Please find below the original query and the modified query. The modified query doesn't return any row but the original returns me 224 rows.

Appreciate any insight on what is wrong with my JOIN query, if it even makes sense to use JOIN instead of subquery in this case. Thanks.

```
select Area_CODE,
       due_DATE,
       RATE,

from SCHED S
where (s.Area_CODE = 11001 and 
   (s.COMP_CODE = 'a' 
   or
      (s.COMPANY_CODE = 'b' 
          and s.due_DATE <
          (
           select
               nvl( min(s1.due_DATE), to_date  ( '31-DEC-2999', 'DD-MM-YYYY') )
               from   SCHED s1
               where  s1.AREA_CODE = s.AREA_CODE 
               and s1.COMP_CODE = 'c'
          )
       )
    )
   )
order by a.EFF_DATE asc, s.due_DATE asc
```

**Modified Query:**

```
SELECT
  Area_CODE,
       due_DATE,
       RATE

from SCHED S
LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      NVL( MIN(s1.due_DATE), to_date ( '31-DEC-2999', 'DD-MM-YYYY') ) AS
      min_date,
      s1.AREA_CODE AS a_code
    FROM
      SCHED s1
    WHERE
      s1.COMPANY_CODE = 'c'
    GROUP BY
      s1.AREA_code
  )
  s2
ON
  s2.A_CODE = s.area_code
WHERE
  (
    s.area_code = 11001
  AND
    (
      s.COMP_CODE = 'a'
    OR
      (
        s.COMP_CODE = 'b' 
      and s.due_DATE < s2.min_date
      )
    )
  )
order by s.EFF_DATE asc, s.due_DATE asc
```

Comment: I think that your join code is fine, but subquery code has an error: `where  s1.AREA_CODE = s1.AREA_CODE`.

Comment: My fault. Edited it to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is where there are no dates for a given area code

Change the left join (s2) to an inner join on

```
inner JOIN 
( 
    SELECT 
        min(s1.due_DATE) AS min_date, 
        s1.AREA_CODE AS a_code 
    FROM 
        (
            select Area_Code, due_date from SCHED WHERE COMPANY_CODE = 'c' 
            union
            select Area_Code, to_date('31-dec-2999','DD-MM-YYYY') from SCHED
        ) s1    
    GROUP BY 
        s1.AREA_code 
) s2
```

Comment: Podiluska, thanks for the reply. It works with your changes but this has become more expensive than the initial query. Any other option to improve the performance? I am using index hints with an index on Area_Code and Due_date

Comment: @dotnetFAQ Is it any quicker if you take the order by clause off? If so, it may be worth considering indexing those fields.  Have you looked at the query plan (`EXPLAIN`) to see where the bottleneck is occurring?